# How can I indent just the portion of a line that wraps within a <p> element?

Tags: html, css

The text for the site that I'm working renders as paragraphs with internal lines separated by `<br>` tags. When a single line runs longer than the container div width and wraps, how can I indent the text that wraps?

I've tried using `margin-left` and `text-indent` on the `<p>` tag, but of course, that just indents everything after the first line of the paragraph, which is not what I'm after.

```html
<p>
Assuming that a containing div width is 27 characters, this line would wrap after the word 'containing', meaning that I'd like indentation for any new line created by wrapping within this sentence.
<br>
Then the start of this line should be aligned with 'Assuming' above, and the following lines created by wrapping (if any) should also be indented.
</p>
```

Comment: if you are able to put each section inside a `span` you can easily do this

Comment: This feels like you’re trying to recreate the presentation of paragraphs, is JavaScript – or a server-side technology – accessible to you? As a quick illustration: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fme8bkc4/).

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm actually looking for the inverse of that, where the *wrapped* lines are indented, not the first line.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I may be able to -- right now, the text is the output of a Markdown -> HTML rendering process that I haven't inspected. If I'm able to update it to output each section inside a `<span>`, what would you recommend?

Comment: a simple padding-left will do it if you are able to use span as wrapper

Comment: @TemaniAfif if you're suggesting that a "section" is equivalent to a portion of the sentence, then no, I can't do that. Line lengths are fluid and not fixed, so I can't break sentences into spans.

Comment: here is what the code will look like: https://jsfiddle.net/j8f6c4ey/